# php / sql - login is failing

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to authenticate a login for my php/sql webpage.

The first code shows part of the Login.php where I take two text fields, email & password, and pass them to authenticate.php

The second code shows where I take the two values and try to process them.

The problem I have having is that I get directed to index.php everyime, even if I have the correct data entered in the field.

Any help would be appreciated.

Part of Login.php

```
        <td width="70">Email</td>
        <td width="6" align="center">:</td>
<form action="authenticate.php" method="post" name="authenticate_form">
        <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="70">Password</td>
        <td width="6" align="center">:</td>
        <td><input name="password" type="text" id="password"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="70">Login</td>
        <td width="6" align="center">:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
        </td>
```

Authenticate.php

```
// ----------------------
// Retrieve login information

include("db_info.php");

// ----------------------

$conn = oci_connect($db_user, $db_pwd, '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=asuka.cs.ndsu.nodak.edu)(Port=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=asuka)))');

if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    print_r($e);
    exit();
}

// ----------------------
// Get POST values

if(isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] && isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password']) {

     // Get posted form information and strip out unsafe characters
     $email = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
 $password = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['password']));
} else {
    // Illegal access.
    // Redirect back to index.php
    header("location: index3.php");
    exit();
}

// ----------------------
// Authenticate User

// Create query
$sql = "SELECT PASSWORD FROM CUSTOMER WHERE EMAIL = '$email'";

 // Create database query statement
$statement_id = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

// Execute query statement
$result = oci_execute($statement_id, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
$queryResult = oci_fetch_row($statement_id);

//var_dump($queryResult);
// Check for successful authentication
if($password == $queryResult[0]) {

if ($email=="admin@hotmail.com") {
    $db_login_status = 2;
    header("location: admin.php");
} else {
    $db_login_status = 1;
    header("location: normal.php");
}
} else {
    header("location: fail.php");
}

// ----------------------
// Close connections

oci_free_statement($statement_id);
oci_close($conn);
```

Comment: It looks like `$result` is undefined; and are you storing passwords in plain-text?

Comment: Crap, I posted the wrong file.. I had that fixed before. Updated, and I am getting sent to index.php every time now.

Comment: I suggest you comment out the `header(` for now and add an output of some sort so you can distinguish whether you're being sent to index.php from the else-branch after authentification or already at the `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {`

Comment: I changed that redirect to index3.php, still getting sent to **index.php** Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: So which one is the one that triggers, the first one after checking request method or the one after checking for `$result`?

Comment: The one inside of the authenticate portion of the code. I will update it on the code shown above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($email=="admin@hotmail.com") {
    $db_login_status = 2;
    header("location: index1.php");
} else {
    $db_login_status = 1;
    header("location: index.php");
}
```

If you are being sent to index.php, that must mean you are not logging in with "admin@hotmail.com". Try using that email address. Otherwise, try removing the code above and just leave these two lines:

```
    $db_login_status = 1;
    header("location: index.php");
```

The thing is that you're not getting redirected *even though* you entered the correct login, you are getting redirected *because* you did so. If you do not want to be redirected upon logging in, you will have to change your script to do whatever you are intending.

Edit: Based on your comment, it seems `$email` is empty. That would be because the `<input name="email">` in your form is a hidden input which is not filled with anything when you type in your password. I was assuming that you had a javascript which imported the values from the visible text inputs in the other table cells. Do you? Otherwise, there's your problem. Your `<form>` tag needs to actually include the inputs which the login data gets entered into. You can solve the problem by wrapping the form around the whole login table.

Apart from that, your `$result` will *always* be 1 because the query succeeded, and not because it contained a result. After that, you additionally need to do `$row = oci_fetch_row($statement_id);`. Then check for `if($row)` rather than `if($statement_id)`. Or simply `if(oci_fetch_row($statement_id))`

As a side note that turned out to be another problem: Don't forget to commit edits which you make to the database on an external editor. If they're not committed, other queries will not see them. In this case, the record for 'admin@hotmail.com' was added in an external program and not committed - so PHP refused to acknowledge the login.

Comment: The problem is that I have tried to use the correct login information for both a standard user and for the admin, both times, and even if I leave the fields blank, I get sent to index.php.

Comment: Sorry, could you give an example? I'm not sure what you mean, I thought this line, <input name="email" type="text" id="email"> would allow the user to enter a value, and this line, <input type="hidden" name="email" value="email" /> would take that value from the field and submit it to the authenticate.

Comment: It doesn't do that automatically. When you submit a form, it submits all the inputs inside the `<form>...</form>` tag. In your case that's two hidden inputs into which the user can't enter anything (unless they use a tool like Firebug which allows editing the page). The two text inputs need to be inside the form tag in order to be submitted, and then you can remove the two hidden inputs. (inputs are not supposed to be used outside forms anyway)

Comment: I updated the first part of the code, Is that how I am suppose to be doing it? I hope I have it wrong because it doesn't work yet.

Comment: That doesn't work because the form, like any other tag, can't randomly interrupt the table. Are there any other forms inside the table; as in, does anything speak against simply putting the `<form>` around the whole `<table>`?

Comment: I put the form around the whole table, I am able to get to the admin page with 'admin@hotmail.com' - does not matter what password I use. Anything else brings me to the normal user login. Thanks for all the help btw.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10675/discussion-between-armatus-and-meowbits)

Answer (score 3):

`$result` is never assigned, therefore it never equals `1`. The fix would be:

```
$result = oci_execute($statement_id, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
// Check for successful authentication
if ($result) {
```

`$result` will be boolean, therefore you don't need to compare it with `1`.

When `$result` returns `false` there is a function to see what went wrong. This function is `oci_error()`. Instead of redirecting you should print (or log) the error. This will aid you with debugging.

The problem could be that you don't have quotes around the parameters in you SQL query.

Comment: Updated, still getting sent to **index.php**

Comment: I changed it to,    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM CUSTOMER WHERE EMAIL='$email' AND PASSWORD='$password'";

Comment: Print your values to see what the contents of your variables are with `echo $email` or `die $email` when they aren't what you expect them to be instead of redirecting. This allows you to debug your yourself, since asking like this isn't going to work.

Comment: Hi Mark, I commented all of the redirects out and replaced them with, die $email. Now I stay on the authenticate page but it is just a blank screen. The same is true if I use echo $email

Comment: Use `print_r` or `var_dump` instead, they're better for debugging because they output variables in a neater way.

Answer (score 2):

`if ($result==1) {}`

$result is never assigned in the code!

Comment: Has been updated, still getting sent to the same page every time.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM CUSTOMER WHERE EMAIL='$email' AND PASSWORD='$password'";

Comment: You forgot the single quotes!

Comment: Hi, for some reason $result is still 0. Just for debugging, try printing $sql just before the executing the query, copy it and then run the same query on your phpmyadmin ( or whatever software you're using). This way you'll be sure that the query is running successfully.

Comment: I am using sqlplus, I ran the query and it returns 1. Also, I believe that $result is = 'true' or 1 because if it was 0 I would be getting sent to index2.php

Comment: Oh sorry my bad, yup $result is 1 (I just forgot to re read the code after replying to another question), then last thing left is to check $email=="admin@hotmail.com", just in the beginning of the page, use print_r($_POST); and also echo $email; after     
$email = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
Then finally use exit(); before 
$result = oci_execute($statement_id, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);

Check if both are admin@hotmail.com else I am out of Ideas

Comment: Thanks for the debugging pointer :) It returns the values that I passed. Array ( [email] => admin@hotmail.com [password] => admin [submit] => Login )

Comment: I updated my authenticate portion, I have **some** success now, If I enter 'admin@hotmail.com' I get to the admin page regardless of the password. anything else even blank sends me to the normal user page.

Comment: Please read :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php

The thing is $result will always be one since the query will always run successfully, even if username and password doesn't match with the ones in database ( no results _BUT_ query ran successfully)

Comment: The only case $result will be 0 or false is when the syntax of the sql query was wrong. To check if the login information is incorrect you will need to use this funtion in the $result==1 loop :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

The case will be if mysql_num_rows==0 then header('index2.php')

Comment: Thanks, I am going to town with var_dump and checking everything.

Comment: Hi! Sure please feel free to ask question in case of doubt. Just to clarify a bit more, the problem is here:
// Check for successful authentication **Actually this doesnot check for successful authentication but for success/failure of the query** A query "Select * FROM CUSTOMER where email = 'anyemail@notinyourdatabase.com'"; will still return $result==1, since the query does ran but result was empty. So Inshort you will reach fail.php if you change the query to something with error like "SELET BLAH BLAH NOT CORRECT"

Comment: Got it fixed, thanks for your help. Will update the final answer.